# pyqt5 file_open method error, i got this error when i opened an image

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
 def open_file(self):
    name=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
    file=open(name, 'rb', encoding= 'utf8')

    self.editor()

    with file:
        text=file.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(text)
```

expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple i got this error when i opened an image.

Comment: `open(name[0],`

Comment: `getOpenFileName` return a tuple with the name and the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getOpenFileName` return a tuple with the name and the extension

```
def open_file(self):
    name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
    file = open(name[0], 'rb', encoding='utf8')

    self.editor()

    with file:
        text = file.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(text)
```

You should also make a test to see if you return something otherwise the program could crash

```
def open_file(self):
    name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
    if name[0] == '':
        return
    file = open(name[0], 'rb', encoding='utf8')

    self.editor()

    with file:
        text = file.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(text)
```